# How to concatenate XHTML files in Java resolving any possible CSS conflicts?

Tags: java, css, html, xhtml, concatenation

I need to concatenate in Java and at runtime XHTML files (containing just formatted text) into a single file. The final file must have all content included in the original ones. However, as these files may have different CSS definitions, I have to resolve any possible collision of styles. I have tried to search for a library that can automate this task and I believe JSoup can help, but it doesn't seem be able to deal with CSS collisions automatically.

Is there another open source framework or API that could make this task easier to implement?

Let me show you an example to explain better what I am trying to do.

```
<!-- File 1 -->
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <style>
      h1 { color: red; }
      .default-stroke { font-weight: bold; }
      #custom-id { font-style: normal;  }
      div.align { position: absolute; right: 800px; width: 300px; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>HTML file 1 Header 1 tag</h1>
    <div class="align">
      <p id="custom-id" class="default-stroke">PARAGRAPH inside DIV</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>

<!-- File 2 -->
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <style>
      h1 { color: blue; }
      .default-stroke { font-weight: italic; }
      div.align { position: absolute; right: 1000px; width: 300px; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>HTML file 2 Header 1 tag</h1>
    <div class="align">
      <p id="custom-id" class="default-stroke">PARAGRAPH inside DIV</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>

<!-- File 3 -->
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <style>
      h1 { color: green; }
      .default-stroke { font-weight: 900; }      
      div.align { position: absolute; right: 1200px; width: 300px; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>HTML file 3 Header 1 tag</h1>
    <div class="align">
      <p id="custom-id" class="default-stroke">PARAGRAPH inside DIV</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Note that all CSS styles (h1, .default-stroke and div.align) have different definitions for each XHTML file. This is what I call a collision. I need to find a way to deal with such collisions, but keeping all styles defined in every file. What is the best way of doing it? May I write my own code to introduce CSS namespaces?

I guess this is not a trivial task. I would appreciate any suggestions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<style scoped>` may help. Put the contents of each of the HTML files in their own sections and put the style blocks in there too, giving them `scoped` attributes. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style

```html
<section>
  <style scoped>
    h1 {
      color: red;
    }
    .default-stroke {
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    #custom-id {
      font-style: normal;
    }
    div.align {
      position: absolute;
      right: 800px;
      width: 300px;
    }
  </style>
  <h1>HTML file 1 Header 1 tag</h1>
  <div class="align">
    <p id="custom-id" class="default-stroke">PARAGRAPH inside DIV</p>
  </div>
</section>
<section>
  <style scoped>
    h1 {
      color: blue;
    }
    .default-stroke {
      font-weight: italic;
    }
    div.align {
      position: absolute;
      right: 1000px;
      width: 300px;
    }
  </style>
  <h1>HTML file 2 Header 1 tag</h1>
  <div class="align">
    <p id="custom-id" class="default-stroke">PARAGRAPH inside DIV</p>
  </div>
</section>
<section>
  <style scoped>
    h1 {
      color: green;
    }
    .default-stroke {
      font-weight: 900;
    }
    div.align {
      position: absolute;
      right: 1200px;
      width: 300px;
    }
  </style>
  <h1>HTML file 3 Header 1 tag</h1>
  <div class="align">
    <p id="custom-id" class="default-stroke">PARAGRAPH inside DIV</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Disclaimer: doesn't work in all browsers (yet).

Comment: This is a good and simple solution, but I had to use a similar one based on <div> and combined css selectors because as you said, not all browsers support <section scoped>. What I did was to change all css styles adding a prefix to avoid collisions. For example: #file-1 h1 {...}. Additionally, I  introduced a <div id="file-1"> and inside it the file-1's body content. This was done for every file. I ran some tests and it is working fine. Thanks!